# Port forwarding my NGINX webserver not working on port 80

Tags: http, nginx, ssl-certificate, router, portforwarding

How can I get the webserver to work on port 80. (So certbot will work)

Tp-Link router
TL-R470T+

Port forwarding rules tried on the router.

1. External: 80 Internal: 8080      - Works
2. External: 80 Internal: 80        - Doesnt work

There is no other port forwardning rule with port 80.

I dont think its a problem with my nginx config as I can access the site on port 80 within the network.

Comment: post nginx config

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.